# How to run XCTest with the open source version of Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

There is an empty test using XCTest:

```
import XCTest
XCTMain([])
```

I want to execute this test with the open source version of Swift (swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-06-a) and without Xcode project file (*.xcodeproj).

Executing `swiftc Tests/main.swift` on Ubuntu Linux (v15.10) was successfully completed, but it was failed on OSX (El Capitan v10.11.2) with following error messages:

```
% swiftc Tests/main.swift
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'CoreGraphics'
<unknown>:0: note: did you forget to set an SDK using -sdk or SDKROOT?
<unknown>:0: note: use "xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc" to select the default OS X SDK installed with Xcode
```

Then I tried executing with `xcrun -sdk macosx` prefix, but another error was occurred:

```
% xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc Tests/main.swift
Tests/main.swift:2:8: error: cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'
import XCTest
       ^
```

Are there any ways to run this test on OSX?